# Excel Macro VBA looping issues- Formatting all tables

Tags: excel, vba

This code is looping through and changing all the table styles but it is not changing all the fonts and sizes. Only the current ws.

```
Sub Format_Tables()
    
    ' Tables_Format Macro

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    'Loop through each worksheet    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
    
            tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"    
            Cells.Select    
            With Selection.Font
                 .Name = "Garamond"
                 .Size = 12
                 .Strikethrough = False
                 .Superscript = False
                 .Subscript = False
                 .OutlineFont = False
                 .Shadow = False
                 .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                 .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                 .TintAndShade = 0
                 .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
            End With
    
            Selection.Rows.AutoFit    
            Selection.Columns.AutoFit    
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"
    
        Next tbl
    
    Next ws

    'MsgBox (Err.Description)  End Sub
```

Comment: `With ws.UsedRange.Font`

Answer (score 1):

`Cells.Select`

in a regular code module will only work on the activesheet, so you just format the same sheet repeatedly.  Try

`With ws.UsedRange.Font`

instead (no need to Select)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change just the data you want to grab the `DataBodyRage`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.ListObject.DataBodyRange

If you want to change the headers you use `HeaderRowRange`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.headerrowrange

EXAMPLE:

```
Public Sub FormatTables()    
    Dim ws As Worksheet        
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
    
            tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"    
              
            With tbl.DataBodyRage.Font
                 .Name = "Garamond"
                 .Size = 12
                 .Strikethrough = False
                 .Superscript = False
                 .Subscript = False
                 .OutlineFont = False
                 .Shadow = False
                 .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                 .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                 .TintAndShade = 0
                 .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
            End With
    
            tbl.DataBodyRage.Rows.AutoFit    
            tbl.DataBodyRage.Columns.AutoFit    
            tbl.DataBodyRage.NumberFormat = "0.000"
        Next tbl   
    Next ws

    'MsgBox (Err.Description)  
End Sub
```